# Parse bunch of JSON Objects in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to parse the following bunch of JSON objects in PHP. But for some extent that doesn't work.

```
[
{"latitute":16.8045558404827,"longitude":36.9140487536788,
    "missionid":0,"status":0,"waypointid":0},
{"latitute":-14.093939943107658,"longitude":21.093734242022038,
    "missionid":0,"status":0,"waypointid":0}
]
```

.

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["waypoints"]);


foreach ($json->items as $item) {

    echo($item->{'longitude'});
    echo($item->{'latitude'});
    echo($item->{'missionid'});
    $query="INSERT INTO dio.wpoint (longitude, latitude, missionid, status, ) VALUES ("$item->{'longitude'}.","$item->{'latitude'}.",41)";
    mysql_query($query);    

}
```

Comment: `latitute` is possibly misspelled?

Comment: `mysql_query()` has an error checking mechanism, `mysql_error()`. It enables you to find out what went wrong yourself.

Comment: Use `$obj` in the for loop, rather than `$json`?

Comment: yes it is misspelled, but thats also in the db. I think there is a problem with the loop. I also changed to $obj. but it didnt work

Comment: So are you going to update your code with the attribute names correct?

Comment: Ah yes, `$json` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$json` as the variable in your foreach loop rather than `$obj`. You also won't need to refer to the member `items` as it doesn't exist in your JSON.

In the query only three values are present, when there should be four to match the column names - I'm not sure exactly what values you want in your query, but I've made an educated guess.

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["waypoints"]);

foreach ($obj as $item) {
    echo $item->{'longitude'};
    echo $item->{'latitude'};
    echo $item->{'missionid'};

    $query="INSERT INTO dio.wpoint (longitude, latitude, missionid, status)
            VALUES (" . $item->{'longitude'} . ", " .
                        $item->{'latitude'} . ", " .
                        $item->{'missionid'} . ", " .
                        $item->{'status'} .
                   ")";
    mysql_query($query);    
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are some inconsistencies with spelling which should be fixed. Depending on your PHP version, `mysql_query` may be deprecated, so it's worth looking into alternatives, such as [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Your query may also be vulnerable to SQL injection, reading [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) should offer guidance.

Comment: Sorry I'm all out of votes for the day! Commenting so I remember to come back in 5 hours

Answer (score 2):

Mysql does not allow trailing commas as far as I know.

```
INSERT INTO dio.wpoint (longitude, latitude, missionid, status, )
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO dio.wpoint (longitude, latitude, missionid, status)
```